# Javascript regex remove all line breaks after comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a simple regex that will remove all line breaks after comma. right know what I'm doing is removing all

```
\n/g
```

what do I need to add in order to remove only after comma?
thanks.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/,\n+/g, ',');`

Comment: @anubhava why not answer?

Comment: I thought it was a minor change in OP's regex. But ++ to both answers

Comment: Actually @anubhava acts as a teacher for newbie respondents like me .. He always support me and my answers. Also I have learned a lot of things from him `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
replace(/,\n/g,"")
```

For example

```
"\n\n,\n".replace(/,\n+/g,",")
```

Answer (score 3):

That's really simple. Try this:

```
/,\n+/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX4oP5/4)

---

**Full Code:**

```
var str = "first line,\nsecond line,\nalso, it is third line,\nand fourth line";
str = str.replace(/,\n+/g, ',');
```

Comment: OP wants to remove line break but keep `,`